# What are configmap.yaml and job.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create Kafka cluster automatically, instead of creation manually, I'm using the stable chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kafka-manager

in the template folder there are two .yaml files: configmap.yaml and job.yaml, what's these files and what's the roles of these files?

Comment: those yaml files you see in the github folder are used to create kubernetes api objects. You can find more in [Kubernetes documentation site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/). [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/). [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

Comment: That repo is not Kafka. It's CDAK, a UI tool for Kafka. Start at http://strimzi.io

Comment: The repository you link explains that this is a Helm chart. You should first review the Helm documentation to understand the structure and purpose of this repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`configMap` is just a way to store non-confidential data in key-value pairs, you can also consume this data as an environment variable from the pods. (it doesn't provide secrecy or encryption!).

`job.yaml` is a supervisor for pods carrying out batch processes, that is, a process that runs for a certain time to completion, for example a calculation or a backup operation.

hope it answers your question, let me know if you need anything else. :)